# Show jasper report HTML page (web app) in Spring roo aplication

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jasper-reports, spring-roo

I'm novice with Spring Roo.

With Spring Roo I created an application.
When I use the Webapp example in the Spring Roo I get good results with the PDF, Word, ....
But the HTML and the "HTML Page By Page Viewer" do not work.
When I change the HTML and the "HTML Page By Page Viewer" to a Hello World, they appear correct. So the JSP pages are correctly declared.
Further I do not get any error.

With the Webapp example code of the JasperReports Library outside of the Spring Roo application I get the desired results, but when I use the same JSP file in my Spring Roo application I get an empty screen.

In the JSP I check that the JasperPrint object is not empty and I can see that it has 10 pages.
`System.out.println("Aantal pagina's = " + jasperPrint.getPages().size());`

In the FileUploadController I set the session attributes.
Then I start the message.jsp file.
This message.jsp file is like the Export page in the JasperReports Webapp example.
The message.jsp file does show up correctly.
Also, all the PDF, Word etc. links work correctly and I do see the correct PDF representation of the Jasper report.
Only the first 2 links, HTML and HTML viewer page by page do not show correctly.
The HTML page is empty. When I change the page with "Hello World" it shows up correctly.

In Spring Roo I have a FileUpload entity.
In the **FileUploadController** I added:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
 public String create(@Valid FileUpload fileUpload, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws URLNotFoundException {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        populateEditForm(uiModel, fileUpload);
        return "fileuploads/create";
    }

    File file = null;
    uiModel.asMap().clear();
    CommonsMultipartFile image = fileUpload.getImage();
    if (image != null) {
        file = new File(image.getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println("Original filename = " + image.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            image.transferTo(file);
            fileUpload.setContentType(image.getContentType());
            fileUpload.setPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
            fileUpload.setRemoteUrl(httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "fileuploads/create";
        }
    }

    File jrPrintFile = file;

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
    try {
        jasperPrint = (JasperPrint)JRLoader.loadObject(jrPrintFile);
    } catch (JRException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute(BaseHttpServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, jasperPrint);
    httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute(ImageServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, jasperPrint);

    httpServletRequest.setAttribute("filePath", file.getAbsolutePath());
    httpServletRequest.setAttribute("message", "The report " + image.getOriginalFilename() + "has been done successfully!");

    fileUpload.persist();
    return "fileuploads/message";
    //  return "redirect:/fileuploads/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(fileUpload.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
 }
 }
```

My **Message.jsp** file is (like the export page in the JasperReports Webapp example)

```
      <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.Date"%>
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
      <html>
            <h3>HTML viewers</h3>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="jasperHtmlView" target="_blank"><span class="desc">HTML
                  viewer</span></a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="jasperViewer" target="_blank"><span class="desc">HTML
                  Page By Page Viewer</span></a>
               </li>
            </ul>
            <h3>PDF viewer</h3>
            <h3>
               <span class="desc"></span>
            </h3>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="servlets/pdf" target="_blank"><span class="desc">PDF
                  export</span></a>
               </li>
            </ul>
            <h3>Office&nbsp; viewers</h3>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="servlets/docx" target="_blank"><span
                  class="desc">Word (DOCX)</span></a></li>
               <li><a href="servlets/xlsx" target="_blank"><span
                  class="desc">Excel (XLSX)</span></a></li>
               <li><a href="servlets/xls" target="_blank"><span class="desc">Excel
                  2003(XLS)</span></a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="servlets/pptx" target="_blank"><span
                  class="desc">PowerPoint (PPTX)</span></a></li>
               <li><a href="servlets/odt" target="_blank"><span class="desc">penDocument
                  Text (ODT)</span></a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="servlets/ods" target="_blank"><span class="desc">OpenDocument
                  Spreadsheet (ODS)</span></a>
               </li>
            </ul>
            <%
               Date created = new Date(session.getCreationTime());
               Date accessed = new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime());
               Date expiry = new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime()
               + session.getMaxInactiveInterval() * 1000);
               %>
            <footer>
               <hr>
               <table style="width: 100%" border="0">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                           <pre>Session ID</pre>
                        </td>
                        <td><%=session.getId()%></td>
                        <td>Method</td>
                        <td><%=request.getMethod()%></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Created</td>
                        <td><%=created%></td>
                        <td>Request URI</td>
                        <td><%=request.getRequestURI()%></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Last Accessed</td>
                        <td><%=accessed%></td>
                        <td>Path Info</td>
                        <td><%=request.getPathInfo()%></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Next expired time</td>
                        <td><%=expiry%></td>
                        <td>Remote Address</td>
                        <td><%=request.getRemoteAddr()%></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
               <hr>
            </footer>
         </body>
      </html>
```

My code in the **html.jsp** lookes like:

```
 <%@ page errorPage="error.jsp" %>
 <%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*" %>
 <%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*" %>
 <%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.*" %>
 <%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.*" %>
 <%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.*" %>
 <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
 <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

 <%
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = (JasperPrint) session.getAttribute(ImageServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE);

    if (jasperPrint == null) {
        throw new JRRuntimeException("File WebappReport.jrprint not found.");
    }
    System.out.println("Jasper print object is NOT null");
    System.out.println("Aantal pagina's = " + jasperPrint.getPages().size());

    session.setAttribute(ImageServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, jasperPrint);

    HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();

    //  session.setAttribute(BaseHttpServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, jasperPrint);

    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_WRITER, out);
    //  exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI, "../servlets/image?image=");
    exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI, "./servlets/image?image=");

    exporter.exportReport();
 %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using gvNIX framework (based on Spring-roo) that implements functionalities to works easily with jasper reports and other interesting functionalities.

Visit the following links to learn more about gvNIX framework:

http://github.com/disid/gvnix
http://code.google.com/p/gvnix/

And here you have an example about how to implement an application with jasper reports using gvNIX:

http://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/tree/master/quickstart-app#reports

Best Regards,